# How to write a bash script that access to database inside docker then insert data?

Tags: bash, docker

Provided, I have to go through a route of

1. Get into docker
2. Get into postgreSQL database
3. Create table
4. Insert data

Which is very troublesome to do it frequently since I am testing. I want to write a bash script (.sh file) that do everything in 1 run.

Here are all my command line I need to run

```
docker exec -it <mycontainer> bash

psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres

CREATE SCHEMA bank;

CREATE TABLE bank.holding (
    holding_id int,
    user_id int,
    holding_stock varchar(8),
    holding_quantity int,
    datetime_created timestamp,
    datetime_updated timestamp,
    primary key(holding_id)
);

insert into bank.holding values (102100, 2, 'VFIAX', 10, now(), now());
```

Comment: You will need to run them one at a time using the `-c` option to `psql`. For example `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -c 'create schema bank;` and then `sql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -c 'create table bank.holding ( ... );` and so on. You can put all your command in a file and then use the `-f` (`--file`) option to read all commands from a file. That would likely be the better call, e.g. `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -f file-w-create.txt`.

Comment: [PostqreSQL Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) provides a way initilize data using scripts. Please read section *Initialization scripts* from its official docs. TLDR; just mount your `sql` scrips inside `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` using docker volumes, and it will run on database init

Comment: Also consider using your application framework's database migration system to run these (and especially the `CREATE TABLE` commands).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it will assist you on automating the procedure if you **expose** your container port

```
docker container run ... -p 5432:5432 ...
```

The above procedure will enable you to access the container port, by directly accessing your `localhost:5432`

Next run

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -f bash_automation_script.txt
```

**bash_automation_script.txt**

```
CREATE SCHEMA bank;

CREATE TABLE bank.holding (
    holding_id int,
    user_id int,
    holding_stock varchar(8),
    holding_quantity int,
    datetime_created timestamp,
    datetime_updated timestamp,
    primary key(holding_id)
);

insert into bank.holding values (102100, 2, 'VFIAX', 10, now(), now());
```